# Integral monotonicity in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ and $g$ two integrable functions of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $f \leq g$

Let $B$ be a compact rectangle containing the support sets of $f$ and $g$.

How can I justify that:

> $\inf \left \{  \mathcal{U}(f,\mathcal{P})\mid \mathcal{P} \text{ is a partition of }B  \right \} \leq \inf \left \{  \mathcal{U}(g,\mathcal{P})\mid \mathcal{P} \text{ is a partition of }B  \right \}$

where $\mathcal{U}(f,\mathcal{P})$ is the upper Darboux sum of $f$.

It bothers me because I don't see how I can compare two arbitrary elements from both sides of the inequality such as $\mathcal{U}(f,\mathcal{P})$ and $\mathcal{U}(g,\mathcal{P^{'}})$.

Thank you.

Comment: Show that the LHS is smaller than $$ \mathcal{U}(f, P)\leq \mathcal{U}(g, P)$$ then take the infimum over all partions $P$ and you're done

Comment: @SeverinSchraven ok so  $\inf \left \{  \mathcal{U}(f,\mathcal{P})\mid \mathcal{P} \text{ is a partition of }B  \right \} \leq \mathcal{U}(f, P)\leq \mathcal{U}(g, P)$ by definition. $\mathcal{U}(f, P)\leq \mathcal{U}(g, P)$ is true. But I also have $\inf \left \{  \mathcal{U}(g,\mathcal{P})\mid \mathcal{P} \text{ is a partition of }B  \right \} \leq \mathcal{U}(g, P)$

Comment: The point is, that in general holds: If $a\leq a_n$ for all $ n\in X$ (where $X$ is some index set), then $a\leq \inf_{n\in X} a_n$. I.e. less or equal is preserved by taking the infimum. This you can deduce immediately from the definition of the infimum. Namely $a$ is a lower bound for $\{ a_n: n\in X\}$, thus the largest lower bound (the infimum) is larger or equal to $a$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Of course! Ï can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Given a partition $P$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we have $U(f,P) \leq U(g,P)$; for, note that $f \leq g$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ implies $\sup f(E) \leq \sup g(E)$ for all $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $\inf_{P} U(f,P) > \inf_{P}U(g,P)$, then there is some partition $P$ such that $U(f,P) \geq \inf_{P}U(f,P) > \frac{\inf_{P}U(f,P) - \inf_{P}U(g,P)}{2} >  U(g,P) \geq \inf_{P}U(g,P)$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\inf_P U(g,P) < \inf_P U(f,P)$.

Take $\epsilon >0$ such that $\inf_PU(g,P) + \epsilon < \inf_P U(f,P)$. It would follow that there exists a partition $P'$ such that $U(f,P') \leqslant U(g,P') < \inf_P U(g,P) + \epsilon < \inf_P U(f,P)$  -- a **contradiction**.